# Huge width of HTML emails in Windows Live Mail?

Tags: html, email, html-email

While trying to design HTML emails, I've noticed that on Windows Live Mail, the emails are not respecting the container, so the email width are gigantic -- thousands of pixels of padding/margin/whatever on the left and right side of the content.

I'm not sure what the reason is; the emails look fine on other clients, including other MS clients. I've also tried wrapping the content in `<!--[if mso]>` tags, but to no avail:

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="600">
<![endif]-->

...

<!--[if mso]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Windows Live Mail is a discontinued product. Development and support was halted in 2014. DeltaSync, the product that helped tie it together with outlook.com has been discontinued as of 30 June 2016. I think it's safe to drop support. Good luck.

Comment: I would second that. Its old and discontinued, not supporting that will be a good idea.

Comment: Any chance you can post your html so we can have a look?